# Create Vagrant Windows Server 2012 box with Active Directory + Forest breaking WinRM

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, vagrant

I followed the instructions on [this blog post](http://dominique.broeglin.fr/2015/11/01/vagrant-windows-lab.html) to get a Vagrant box with Windows Server 2012 R2 eval. Then I tried to install Active Directory Domain Controller and an Active Directory Forest (with first domain) using Vagrant provisioning feature. PowerShell scripts are from the same blog, see [here](https://github.com/dbroeglin/windows-lab/tree/master/provision). However, after the installation of the AD forest - which needs a reboot -, Vagrant is losing WinRM connection with the following error and doesn't continue with provisioning:

```
Error occurred: An authorization error occurred while connecting to WinRM.

User: vagrant
Endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:5985/wsman
Message: WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError
```

It seems that the AD forest installation breaks network/authentication until Windows is rebooted. The actual installation seems to be successful. But the problem is that the provisioning was not done completely (I have a script that would add a new AD user after forest is installed).

Any ideas how to fix that?

Maybe as a work-around: Is it possible to setup a script that runs AD forest installation on Windows startup such that no reboot is required?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probelm and just found the solution.
Add these to your machine config.

```
cfg.winrm.transport = :plaintext
cfg.winrm.basic_auth_only = true
```

and then reboot the machine if you need to do more provisioning after that step.

In that case use the vagrant-reload plugin to do reboot during provisioning. Like this

```
adfs.vm.provision "shell", path: "create-domain.ps1"
adfs.vm.provision "reload"
adfs.vm.provision "shell", path: "more-provisioning.ps1"
```